# audio recorder for safari desktop in html 5

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I had searched for html 5 audio support for safari desktop on many websites.But i didn't get my answer.Please help me.I am new to html 5 & javascript.
I am having a code which is working on firefox & chrome.But its giving a problem in safari.
the problem is something like get user media() is not supported by safari.
 i had copied my code from this site.
here is the link of that.
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html
i copied this code as it is.and running on safari.but its not working.
so plz fix it.

Comment: Hi, can you show us your code?

Comment: yeah...i had copied the code.i ll show u..

Comment: i had attached the link above in my problem.i hope u ll get it soon.waiting for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

getUserMedia API is the current W3C [specification](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) for accessing audio recording device but is still in draft. I am not aware of anything that can be done in HTML5 without the getUserMedia API for recording audio.

As stated here http://caniuse.com/stream, neither current versions of Safari (desktop or iOS) nor Internet explorer support the getUserMedia API. Until the browser manufacturers implement the W3C specification for the getUserMedia API you will need to use good old plugins like Flash or Java to cover the browser you want.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your support.but i want to implement it without flash.so please give me some solution without flash.thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, what Arnaud said is true. There is NO non-Flash-based solution for Safari desktop. So no one can give you a solution for Safari that does not use flash.